# Why and how are mushrooms growing in my indoor house plant soil?

Tags: houseplants, mushrooms, peace-lily

Every day I check my peace lily to see if it needs watering, and now there are two mushrooms growing in the pot! Please let me know why & how they are growing there and what I should do with them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Joseph. I had lots of those cute things in my pre-mixed potting soil, especially during the time I had my plants under gro-lights. I don't touch anything that doesn't seem to be doing damage, so I just left them alone, and they flopped over and shriveled up after a few weeks. It happened several times, and never had an adverse effect on what I was growing!

Comment: Yup that's what I found when I got home today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's nothing to worry about. Most potting mediums these days have a high proportion of composted materials within them. Sometimes the composting process is incomplete, but either way, fungal mycorrhizae are present in the soil, and yours are happy enough to produce a fruiting body or two - the mushrooms you're seeing. Just pick them off and bin them if you don't like the look of them. The majority of mycorrhizal activity within soil is beneficial to plants. The mushrooms may recur, they may not.

Comment: Bamboo I'll taking your word that it's nothing to worry about and that it benefits the plant so I'll  let it be for now and it's cool ;)

Comment: I'd still take the mushrooms off - they drop zillions of spores all the time they're present.... take one off and leave it on some kitchen or white paper, stalk removed, underside down if you're interested- there'll be a pattern of spores when you take it off, fascinating stuff.